# View on top of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a nav bar that is not displaying, in the 3D view hierarchy I can see that the front view hides the nav bar. See the screens below.

The second screen is one with the same class but displayed from another flow.

[image: First screen (Wrong one)]

[image: Second screen (Good one with a custom view added that is ok)]

Comment: Your navBar is a custom navBar?

Comment: @ReinierMelian No, but I found the problem! Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem! I was using MeryPopin CocoaPod and when I did dismissCurrentPopIn with animated = true the nav bar disappeared but when I changed to false it worked. I hope it might be some bug.